# Storing Data in a temporary Table

Tags: .net, sql-server, vb.net, datagridview

I have three tables Items, Invoice and InvoiceItems. When a customer Issues an Invoice, he/she has the option to add one or more items in invoice.

When the customer adds an item in Invoice, It should be added in a DataGridView, from items table (He can add or remove items  before saving invoice). Finally when he saves the invoice, the items that were in gridview, they should be copied in InvoiceItems which has a foreign key relationship with invoice table.

I am confused, how to do that. Should I use a temporary table, for storing temporary items in invoice, I have to clean it (Delete everything in it) every time when the user issues an invoice?

Or should I create a new table (for storing items) every time user issues an invoice, and delete it when he exits from invoice?

I am using Vb.net, and SQL Server Database.

(Please note that I don't store items directly in InvoiceItems, because the invoice row only gets created when user saves the invoice, there is no point in saving items in InvoiceItems table, if the user don't save invoice after adding items into it.)

Comment: DataGridView *is* a temporary table.

Comment: Show how you are populating / binding the DataGridView

Answer (score 1):

'The question is old but I can give some help
'Assuming you have three items in your Mysql Table (Item1, Item2, and item3)

```
Protected Sub Button16_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button16.Click
Dim xx As String
Dim connString2 = New MySqlConnection("server=XXXXX; user id=YYYYY; 
password=WWWWWW; database=DDDDDD; pooling=false;")
connString2.Open()
5:  xx = xx + 1  'This is to make a counter
If xx = 31 Then GoTo 11
Dim sqlQuery1 As String = "SELECT * FROM NameofYourtable where  Condition= '" & 
xxxxxxxx.Text & "'"
Using sqlComm As New MySqlCommand()
With sqlComm
            .CommandText = sqlQuery1
        End With
        Try
            sqlComm.Connection = connString2
            Dim sqlReader As MySqlDataReader = sqlComm.ExecuteReader()
            While sqlReader.Read()
                If Val(sqlReader("NRaws")) = xx Then GoTo 9  (NRaws is the number of raw that will be modified every adding process)
            End While
        Catch ex As MySqlException
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "AlertMessageBox", "alert('Databse Error');", True)

        End Try
    End Using
    connString2.Close()
    GoTo 11

    9:      GoTo 5

    11:     If xx > 30 Then ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(),  "AlertMessageBox", "alert('You reached the maximum number of added items');", True) : GoTo    2
   Dim con1= New MySqlConnection("server=XXXXX; user id=YYYYY; password=WWWWWW; database=DDDDDD; pooling=false;")
    con1.Open()
    Using cmd As New MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO NameofYourtable (NRaws,item1,item2, itemr)VALUES ('" & xx & "','" & xxxx1.Text & "','" & xxxx2.Text & "','" & xxxxx3.Text & "')")
        cmd.Connection = con1
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        con1.Close()
    End Using
    GridviewLoad() 'Call the Sub
2:

Sub GridviewLoad()
Dim con= New MySqlConnection("server=XXXXX; user id=YYYYY; password=WWWWWW; database=DDDDDD; pooling=false;")
Using cmd As New MySqlCommand("select item1,item2,item3 from NameofYourtable where Condition='" & xxxxxxxx.Text & "' order by NRaws", con)
            con.Open()
            Dim ds As New DataSet()
            Using da As New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)
                da.Fill(ds)
                GridView.DataSource = ds
                GridView.DataBind()
            End Using
            con.Close()
        End Using
    End Using
    GridView.HeaderRow.Cells(0).Text = "RawNumber"
    GridView.HeaderRow.Cells(1).Text = "item1"
    GridView.HeaderRow.Cells(2).Text = "item2"
    GridView.HeaderRow.Cells(3).Text = "item3"
            GridView.HeaderRow.Cells(0).Width = 5%
        End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for contribution.